# How does Priority queue compare and maintIn heap property during the pop operation

Tags: c++, stl, heap, priority-queue

I was working on Priority queue and I wanted to check how the heap property is maintained during pop operation. This was my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class g {
    public:
        bool operator() (int a, int b) {
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<endl;
            return (a > b);
        }
};

int main() {
    priority_queue<int,vector<int>,g> p;
    p.push(2);
    cout<<"CHECK1"<<endl;
    p.push(4);
    cout<<"CHECK2"<<endl;
    p.push(8);
    cout<<"CHECK3"<<endl;
    p.push(1);
    cout<<"CHECK4"<<endl;
    while(!p.empty()) {
        cout<<p.top()<<endl;
        p.pop();
    }
}
```

The output was

```
CHECK1
2 4
CHECK2
2 8
CHECK3
4 1
2 1
CHECK4
1
8 2
2 4
2
4 8
4
8
```

This is the binary heap which is built:
         1
       2   8
   4

I see that when 1 is popped out, it gets replaced with 4 and then 2 gets replaced with 4 to maintain heap property and binary heap
                                       2
                                     4   8
then 8 gets replaced with 2 when 2 is popped out then 4 gets replaced with 8 to maintain heap property then 4 gets replaced with 8 when 4 is popped out and at last 8 gets popped out.  Therefore the output according to me is

```
CHECK1
2 4
CHECK2
2 8
CHECK3
4 1
2 1
CHECK4
1
4 2
2 8
2
8 4
4
8
```

where am I wrong ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Are you trying to implement a min heap?

Comment: Yes I wrote the code for minheap and got the output I had written first. But I do not understand how that output came and expected the output I had given at last . And I have also given explanation why I expected the second output.

Answer (score 0):

On your first call to

```
p.push(2)
```

The node 2 gets added to your heap, resulting in

```
 2
/ \
```

We then add 4, which gets added to the left-most open position, resulting in

```
  2
 / \
4
```

Heap property is maintained since 2 < 4, we then add 8 to the next open position

```
  2
 / \
4   8
```

Heap property is still maintained, finally we add 1.

```
    2
   / \
  4   8
 /
1
```

Heap property is violated since 1 < 4, so we sift up or swap nodes 4 and 1, resulting in:

```
    2
   / \
  1   8
 /
4
```

Heap property is still violated since 1 < 2, as a result we sift up once more, resulting in:

```
    1
   / \
  2   8
 /
4
```

Now to your question. On our first call to top, we return the min of our heap, which in our case is 1. We then pop 1, decrease the heap size by 1, and copy the last value in our heap to the root, resulting in:

```
  4
 / \
2   8
```

Because 2 < 4, the heap property is violated, which requires a sift up, resulting in:

```
  2
 / \
4   8
```

We continue in this way until the heap is empty. I leave it to you to figure out the rest. Hope this helps.

Comment: Starting from where I left off, 2 gets popped off, then 8 becomes the new root, 4 < 8, so 4 and 8 are swapped, 4 is the new root, it then gets popped, and 8 is the only node left, so that becomes the root.

Comment: Sir , from here only my dought starts . After Check 4      During top and pop operation the output of last while loop is what I have shown in first output table  but I had expect  to be outputted is shown in second output table so where am I wrong.

Comment: Sir, Please the difference in output after Check 4 (line 2,3,5).Please explain that part.

Comment: I don't know if I can explain this any further. 8 and 2 get compared, 2 becomes new root, 2 is compared with 4 to make sure heap property is satisfied, it is so 2 remains the root, 2 is then popped, 8 becomes new root, 4 and 8 are then compared, 4 < 8 so 4 becomes new root, 4 is then popped, and finally 8 is the only node left so it is popped.